# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } {n \choose k} a^n = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $k$ a  fixed positive integer and $0<a<1$ a real number. Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \left( \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\right) a^n = 0$ .

I stuck in this limit i remember that ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} $ and $|\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} a^n - 0| < |\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} | $  for $0<a<1$ but i have problems to simplify this expression , some help please.

Comment: For fixed $k$, $\binom{n}{k}$ is a polynomial in $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b=\frac{1}{a}$. Then $\binom{n}{k}a^n=\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{b^n}$.

Since $\binom{n}{k}$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ in $n$, applying L'Hospital's Rule $k$ times does the job.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\dbinom{n}{k}$ is a $k$-th degree polynomial in $n$.

Write the limit as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{(1/a)^n}$, then use L'Hopital's rule $k$ times, to get that this limit is $0$.

Comment: On my screen it says that my answer was posted 14 minutes ago and  Andre's answer was posted 10 minutes ago. So, Andre's was posted 4 minutes after mine. Does your screen say differently?

Comment: Ok, so that means I posted ~4 minutes before he did, right?

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry about that. I am extremely sleepy now, and I was not thinking correctly. Again, I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a^n  n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1) = 0$$

(Do you see why?)

In particular, we have the estimate

$$n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdot (n - k + 1) \lesssim n^k$$

where $\lesssim$ means 'up to a constant.'